# How do I use Piecewise Afﬁne Transformation to straighten curved text line/ contour?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, geometry, scikit-image

Consider the following image:
[image]

and the following bounding contour( which is a smooth version of the output of a text-detection neural network of the above image ), so this contour is a given.
[image]

I need to warp both images so that I end up with a straight enough textline, so that it can be fed to a text recognition neural network:
[image]

using Piecewise Afﬁne Transformation, or some other method. with an implementation if possible or key points of implementation in python.

I know how to find the medial axis, order its points, simplify it (e.g using Douglas-Peucker algorithm), and find the corresponding points on a straight line.

EDIT: the question can be rephrased -naively- as the following :
have you tried the "puppet warp" feature in Adobe Photoshop? you specify "joint" points on an image , and you move these points to the desired place to perform the image warping, we can calculate the source points using a simplified medial axis (e.g 20 points instead of 200 points), and calculate the corresponding target points on a straight line, **how to perform Piecewise Afﬁne Transformation using these two sets of points( source and target)?**

EDIT: modified the images, my bad

### Papers

Here's a paper that does the needed result:
[A Novel Technique for Unwarping Curved Handwritten Texts Using Mathematical Morphology and Piecewise Affine Transformation](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/328764249_A_Novel_Technique_for_Unwarping_Curved_Handwritten_Texts_Using_Mathematical_Morphology_and_Piecewise_Affine_Transformation)

another paper: [A novel method for straightening curved text-lines in stylistic documents](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/1687-5281-2014-36)

### Similar questions:

- [Straighten B-Spline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42015693/straighten-b-spline)
- [Challenge : Curved text extraction using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62374861/challenge-curved-text-extraction-using-python)
- [How to convert curves in images to lines in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61725926/how-to-convert-curves-in-images-to-lines-in-python)
- [Deforming an image so that curved lines become straight lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558382/deforming-an-image-so-that-curved-lines-become-straight-lines)
- [Straightening a curved contour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645077/straightening-a-curved-contour)

Comment: please state a question. -- start by finding the medial axis of that thing. I know it's not "a straight line", so perhaps you're asking about that?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I attached an image with the result needed.

Comment: Translate every single column so that the medial axis is at the wanted y coordinate.

Comment: The problem is insufficiently specified, you need to show how the 2D space around the curve should be transformed. Otherwise, you could just join the two endpoint with a simple line segment.

Comment: welll once you have a path, you can easily walk it in unit increments, calculate normals, and use points along the normals to sample the source image, and there you go. the "hard part" is getting a clean path that represents this sausage. skeletonization results are notoriously "linty"

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, can you provide some links ? I don't know what are 'normals' or 'walk it in unit increments'

Comment: @Micka can you provide a link for some code doing that , or something similar?

Comment: @YvesDaoust sorry, edited the question , hope it's more clear now

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz  also please take a look at the first paper I mentioned, I can calculate the source points and the target points just as seen in the paper, I need to warp the image using these two sets of points

Comment: *that* type of path-following just renders the text with shifted y coordinate instead of making it follow the path perpendicularly. to fix that, just unshift all the pixels. please review [ask]. show your own attempt. "piecewise affine transform" surely has been asked and answered before. I don't see why this is a problem.

Comment: The contour does not match the warped text ! :-(

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz, thanks, you're right, after a couple of minutes of search I found an implementation of Piecewise Affine Transform and posted an answer, next time I'll do more research first, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to just unshift each column, then:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

source_img = Image.open("73614379-input-v2.png")
contour_img = Image.open("73614379-map-v3.png").convert("L")
assert source_img.size == contour_img.size

contour_arr = np.array(contour_img) != 0  # convert to boolean array
col_offsets = np.argmax(
    contour_arr, axis=0
)  # find the first non-zero row for each column
assert len(col_offsets) == source_img.size[0]  # sanity check
min_nonzero_col_offset = np.min(
    col_offsets[col_offsets > 0]
)  # find the minimum non-zero row

target_img = Image.new("RGB", source_img.size, (255, 255, 255))
for x, col_offset in enumerate(col_offsets):
    offset = col_offset - min_nonzero_col_offset if col_offset > 0 else 0
    target_img.paste(
        source_img.crop((x, offset, x + 1, source_img.size[1])), (x, 0)
    )

target_img.save("unshifted3.png")
```

with [the new input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvqwc.png) and [the new contour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycUrl.png) from OP outputs this image:

[image]

Comment: This residual undulation is unexpected. Do you have an explanation ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes – my contour was pretty shit and non-smooth since I made it in 15 seconds by blurring and thresholding the text in Affinity Photo.

Comment: Mh, I see, the images provided by the OP don't even match !

Comment: @akk, modified the images, my bad

Comment: @yazansayed Refreshed this with your new data.

Comment: @akk thanks alot, I also posted an answer using PiecewiseAffineTransform , the outputs are pretty similar

Answer (score 2):

Full code also available in [this notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13dsm6ggltYKypukLOw7Hfhkh6lWFhaQc?usp=sharing) , `runtime -> run all` to reproduce the result.

```
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy.spatial import distance
from shapely.geometry import LineString, GeometryCollection, MultiPoint
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from warp import PiecewiseAffineTransform  # https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TimSC/image-piecewise-affine/master/warp.py


# Helper functions

def extendline(line, length):
    a = line[0]
    b = line[1]
    lenab = distance.euclidean(a, b)
    cx = b[0] + ((b[0] - a[0]) / lenab * length)
    cy = b[1] + ((b[1] - a[1]) / lenab * length)
    return [cx, cy]


def XYclean(x, y):
    xy = np.concatenate((x.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1)
    # make PCA object
    pca = PCA(2)
    # fit on data
    pca.fit(xy)
    # transform into pca space   
    xypca = pca.transform(xy)
    newx = xypca[:, 0]
    newy = xypca[:, 1]
    # sort
    indexSort = np.argsort(x)
    newx = newx[indexSort]
    newy = newy[indexSort]

    # add some more points (optional)
    f = interpolate.interp1d(newx, newy, kind='linear')
    newX = np.linspace(np.min(newx), np.max(newx), 100)
    newY = f(newX)

    # #smooth with a filter (optional)
    # window = 43
    # newY = savgol_filter(newY, window, 2)

    # return back to old coordinates
    xyclean = pca.inverse_transform(np.concatenate((newX.reshape(-1, 1), newY.reshape(-1, 1)), axis=1))
    xc = xyclean[:, 0]
    yc = xyclean[:, 1]
    return np.hstack((xc.reshape(-1, 1), yc.reshape(-1, 1))).astype(int)


def contour2skeleton(cnt):
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cnt_trans = cnt - [x, y]
    bim = np.zeros((h, w))
    bim = cv2.drawContours(bim, [cnt_trans], -1, color=255, thickness=cv2.FILLED) // 255
    sk = skeletonize(bim > 0)
    #####
    skeleton_yx = np.argwhere(sk > 0)
    skeleton_xy = np.flip(skeleton_yx, axis=None)
    xx, yy = skeleton_xy[:, 0], skeleton_xy[:, 1]
    skeleton_xy = XYclean(xx, yy)
    skeleton_xy = skeleton_xy + [x, y]
    return skeleton_xy


mm = cv2.imread('cont.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.imshow(mm)
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mm.astype('uint8'), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cont = cnts[0].reshape(-1, 2)

# find skeleton
sk = contour2skeleton(cont)
mm = np.zeros_like(mm)
cv2.polylines(mm, [sk], False, 255, 2)
plt.imshow(mm)

# simplify the skeleton
ln = LineString(sk).simplify(2)
sk_simp = np.int0(ln.coords)
mm = np.zeros_like(mm)
for pt in sk_simp:
    cv2.circle(mm, pt, 5, 255, -1)
plt.imshow(mm)

# extend both ends of the skeleton
print(len(sk_simp))

a, b = sk_simp[1], sk_simp[0]
c1 = np.int0(extendline([a, b], 50))
sk_simp = np.vstack([c1, sk_simp])
a, b = sk_simp[-2], sk_simp[-1]
c2 = np.int0(extendline([a, b], 50))
sk_simp = np.vstack([sk_simp, c2])

print(len(sk_simp))

cv2.circle(mm, c1, 10, 255, -1)
cv2.circle(mm, c2, 10, 255, -1)
plt.imshow(mm)

########
# find the target points
########

pts1 = sk_simp.copy()

dists = [distance.euclidean(p1, p2) for p1, p2 in zip(pts1[:-1], pts1[1:])]
zip1 = list(zip(pts1[:-1], dists))

# find the first 2 target points
a = pts1[0]
b = a - (dists[0], 0)

pts2 = [a, b, ]
for z in zip1[1:]:
    lastpt = pts2[-1]
    pt, dst = z
    ln = [a, lastpt]
    c = extendline(ln, dst)
    pts2.append(c)

pts2 = np.int0(pts2)

ln1 = LineString(pts1)
ln2 = LineString(pts2)
GeometryCollection([ln1.buffer(5), ln2.buffer(5),
                    MultiPoint(pts2), MultiPoint(pts1)])

########
# create translated copies of source and target points

# 50 is arbitary
pts1 = np.vstack([pts1 + [0, 50], pts1 + [0, -50]])
pts2 = np.vstack([pts2 + [0, 50], pts2 + [0, -50]])
MultiPoint(pts1)

########
# performing the warping

im = Image.open('orig.png')
dstIm = Image.new(im.mode, im.size, color=(255, 255, 255))

# Perform transform
PiecewiseAffineTransform(im, pts1, dstIm, pts2)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.imshow(dstIm)
```

1- find medial axis , e.g using `skimage.morphology.skeletonize` and simplify it ,e.g using `shapely object.simplify` , I used a tolerance of 2 , the medial axis points are in white:
[image]

2- find the corresponding points on a straight line, using the distance between each point and the next:
[image]

3 - also added extra points on the ends, colored blue, so that the points fit the entire contour length
[image]

4- create 2 copies of the source and target points, one copy translated up and the other translated down (I choose an offset of 50 here), so the source points are now like this, please note that simple upward/downward displacement may not be the best approach for all contours, e.g if the contour is curving with degrees > 45:
[image]

5- using the code [here](https://github.com/TimSC/image-piecewise-affine/blob/master/warp.py) , perform `PiecewiseAffineTransform` using the source and target points, here's the result, it's straight enough:
[image]

Comment: I mean, shouldn't you post the code too? Also, if this requires manual addition of points, it's... a bit iffy?

Comment: it's not manual addition, for example we have a line from `pts_orig[2]` to `pts_orig[1]`, just extend it by a large enough distance, e.g 50, this distance can be determind based on the "stroke width" of the contour, or we can use the intersection point of that extended line and the contour ,,, the steps are self-explanatory, I didn't think I should add code , but I will, sorry (or maybe my code is ugly :) , will refine it and post it though)

Comment: meant from `pts_orig[1]` to `pts_orig[0]` ,  or the other end `pts_orig[-2]` to `pts_orig[-1]`

Comment: @AKX added link to notebook with full code

Comment: A link to a notebook is effectively a "link-only answer". (Think about what will happen if the Colab file is deleted.)

Comment: @AKX , oh you're right, will add code here

Comment: I exported the code from your colab – I think there are still "no-op" things that would only make sense in a cell.